# Site-specific User-Agent Safari

Tags: snow-leopard, safari, internet

Is there a way to set a site-specific user-agent for Safari? A website for school says it needs Firefox 3.x, but I have found that Safari 5 works fine. The problem is that every time I tried to log in, it warned me that my browser may not work. I set the default user agent to Firefox 3.6, and it worked fine. Now, big sites like Google and Pandora won't allow me to use certain services. (In Gmail, it just goes back to HTML. In Pandora, it blocks the whole site.) I don't want to use a different browser just for one website, and use another for everything else. I also don't want to manually change the user-agent every time I try to go to another page. Is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: Sadly it looks like this is still impossible as recently as June 2021.  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252894112?answerId=252894112021#252894112021

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://www.quora.com/Safari-web-browser/Is-there-a-Safari-plugin-or-extension-that-automatically-modifies-the-browsers-user-agent-for-specific-websites)’s a two-year-old topic on Quora asking the same question. No answer yet.

This leads me to believe there is a way to do what you want. Always changing the UA string using the menu is annoying, but at least it works.

The [Opera](http://www.opera.com/) web browser has a feature that does what you want. But of course, if you have to install a separate browser anyway, you may just as well install Firefox 3.6 and use that to access the site you’re talking about.

Comment: Thanks! I installed Opera and it is working quite nicely.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to just download Firefox 3.6 and use that for the school site and use Safari for everything else. You may also want to bother your school's IT so they remove the useless warning for compatible browsers.